# Django ModelForm foreign key referenece

Tags: django, django-forms

I have defined couple of Models with Foreign Key Reference - UserType is a master table where I have few Types and which can be mapped for a user, many users can have same user type. After this I have created FormModel which works as expected.

```
Class UserType(models.Model):

    user_type_id        = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_type_name_en      = models.CharField(max_length=15)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user_type_name_en

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'usertype'

class User(models.Model):

    user_id             = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    email_id            = models.EmailField( blank=False, null=False)
    user_type           = models.ForeignKey(UserType )
```

UserRegistrationForm

```
class UserRegistrationForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ['email_id',  'password', 'first_name' , 'last_name' , 'user_type' , 'corporate' ]
```

In View.Py

```
def registerUser(request): 
    print 'registerUser'
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save ()
```

I'm getting Drop Down for User Type in HTML where in which 'user_type_name_en' gets displayed. When I save the form it says 'user_type_id' is unknown column. Also, Im able to access only Text not the values which is associated with the drop down item. How to get them?

Comment: did you add `user_type_id` _after_ you did a syncdb ?

Comment: Hi I have updated my question with complete code., could any one help me ?